# Parallel function from joblib running whole code apart from functions

Tags: python, parallel-processing, joblib

I am using **Parallel** function from **joblib** package in Python. I would like to use this function only for handle one of my functions but unfortunately the whole code is running in parallel (apart from other functions).

Example:

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
print ('I do not want this to be printed n times')
def do_something(arg):
    some calculations(arg)

Parallel(n_jobs=5)(delayed(do_something)(i) for i in range(0, n))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common error to miss a design direction from documentation. Many users meet this very same piece of experience.

Documentation is quite clear about **not placing any code but `def`-s** before a **`__main__`** fuse.

If not doing so, errors indeed spray out and things turn wreck havoc, but still, an explicit advice to re-read the documentation is still present there, leaking infinitely over the screen:

```
[joblib] Attempting to do parallel computing
without protecting your import on a system that does not support forking.

To use parallel-computing in a script, you must protect your main loop
using "if __name__ == '__main__'".

Please see the joblib documentation on Parallel for more information
```

---

### Solution:

Having properly done the first issue, reported w.r.t. the fused `import` protection, things will get better:

```
C:\Python27.anaconda>python joblib_example.py
I do not want this to be printed n-times...
I do not want this to be printed n-times...
I do not want this to be printed n-times...
I do not want this to be printed n-times...
I do not want this to be printed n-times...
I do not want this to be printed n-times...
```

next a final touch and you are done:

```
from sklearn.externals.joblib  import Parallel, delayed

def do_some_thing( arg ):
    pass
    return True

if  __name__ == '__main__': #################################### A __main__ FUSE:

    pass;                                   n = 6
    print "I do not want this to be printed n-times..."

    Parallel( n_jobs = 5 ) ( delayed( do_some_thing )( i )
                                                   for i in range( 0, n )
                             )
```

---

```
C:\Python27.anaconda>python joblib_example.py
I do not want this to be printed n-times...

C:\Python27.anaconda>
```

Comment: Thank you! 
I did know how this function works - just wanted to know some workaround and your simple approach is pretty good, just smiled I did not  think about it :) One thing here, I have a lot of local/global variables defined at the beginning so I will have to put them as well in the main part. I am thinking about some other package to use as an alternative. Any ideas? Dask package maybe?

Comment: And one thing, I forgot to add "if __name__ == '__main__'" in my question but I have it in my code - without this, Parallel function does not work.